# "Anding" n arguments in es6 function with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I have to consider huge number of parameters for "and" and then perform operation on template.

So, I created below helper at the client side.

```
Template.registerHelper('isIdle', function (...arg) {
  // how to loop and do "AND" operation with all arugments here.
});
```

from UI, I can pass any number of arguments as below

```
{{isIdle isOnline isWorking isMoving isUsingChrome}}
```

how to loop through 'n' arguments and do AND Operation? all I want to check is `(isOnline && isWorking && .......)` and so on

Comment: All `isXXX` are boolean?

Comment: u can use a forEach() or reduce() or map() function . See lodash's methods . I would recommend using reduce().

Comment: @dfsq: it doesn't matter, if it is `undefined` or `null` it will return `false`

Comment: it does matter for implementation. so it can be not only booleans but whatever?

Comment: @dfsq: Yes. It can be other than boolean as well. updated question as well for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce`:

```js
function and(...arg) {
    return arg.reduce( (res, bool) => res && bool );
}

// Example calls:
console.log(and(true)); // true
console.log(and(false)); // false
console.log(and(true, true)); // true
console.log(and(true, false)); // false
```

If you want to accept the case where no arguments are passed to this function, and expect the function to interpret this as a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), you could use the second argument of `reduce`:

```js
function and(...arg) {
    return arg.reduce( (res, bool) => res && bool, true );
}

console.log(and()); // true
```

Comment: I almost did it, but you posted answer.. thanks a lot @trincot

Comment: any suggestion for good resource to learn es6 (only text , no videos :) )

Comment: Maybe [this list of articles on mozilla.org](https://hacks.mozilla.org/category/es6-in-depth/)?

Comment: Better also pass `true` as an initial accumulator to make `and()` work as expected.

Comment: @Bergi, added that as an option to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to Meteor Implementation, it would look like below;

```
Template.registerHelper('isIdle', function (...args) {
  return args.reduce((previous, current) => previous && current);
});
```